# Getting the current projection matrix

Tags: processing

How do I get and set the current projection matrix in Processing (version 4 beta, P3D renderer) ? Processing provides `printProjection()`; but doesn't provide a way of getting the data. Current transformation matrix can be saved, get and set using `pushMatrix()`, `getMatrix()`, and `setMatrix()`. Is there and equivalent (or a foolproof work around) for projection matrices ?

I searched the javadoc version of the documentation and couldn't find anything.

I attempted to see what `printProjection()` does in the source code.
[PApplet.g](https://github.com/processing/processing4/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java#L13698) ->
[PGraphicsOpenGL.projection](https://github.com/processing/processing4/blob/c9b8a00e7dae72f96688216afe51b0cf755aa639/core/src/processing/opengl/PGraphicsOpenGL.java#L4601) ->
[PMatrix3D](https://github.com/processing/processing4/blob/c9b8a00e7dae72f96688216afe51b0cf755aa639/core/src/processing/core/PMatrix3D.java#L96) and
[PGraphicsOpenGL.pushProjection](https://github.com/processing/processing4/blob/c9b8a00e7dae72f96688216afe51b0cf755aa639/core/src/processing/opengl/PGraphicsOpenGL.java#L4098). Both objects `g` and `projection` are public members.

Origin of this question : I have a class which sets up the camera (It calls `camera()` and `perspective()`). I have another class which needs to *temporarily* reset the transformation and projection matrix so that it can overlay `text()` on the screen. The transformation matrix can be easily `push`ed and `pop`ed. Is there an equivalent for the projection matrix.

I do not want to manually keep track of the calls to `perspective()` which sets the projection matrix. One reason is that it will become a burden on the end user and another reason is that I need the original projection matrix set by the `size()` function to be able to properly place `text()` on the screen.